# Delphi RAD STUDIO android app overlap with status bar on kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm testing simple delphi app on android but the result app is overlap with the status bar on the device. I am using android kitkat 4.4.2 and delphi xe8. Here is the screenshot: 
[image: app shown on device]

I know that delphi is using firemonkey that render the gui using OpenGL. So I try to make simple project on android studio to test openGL on my device, to know if it is overlap or not. But the result app is shown normal. So I guess it's internal delphi operation (or configuration maybe) that make this problem.

So how can I make the delphi app shows normal on my device (app below the status bar)?

Note: I try it on android ice cream sandwich and jelly bean, the app is shown normal and not overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found some workaround for this.

I get status bar height using `getResource` method and set form's top padding using that value. But because of the status bar height value is different than on delphi form (in my case it has more value), I must adjust it by divide it by content height multiply by form height. I think it is related with pixel and density pixel. I haven't clear understand about it, so I just using logic.

Here is the code:

```
uses
    Androidapi.Helpers,
    Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
    Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
    AndroidApi.Jni.App;

Procedure TForm1.setPadding();
var
  statusbarHeight,FormStatusbarHeight,contentHeight:integer;
  view:JView;
begin
  if top=0 then begin    

    //get status bar height
    SharedActivity.getResources.getIdentifier(StringToJString('status_bar_height'),
          StringToJString('dimen'),
          StringToJString('android'));
    if resourceID>0 then begin
      statusBarHeight:=resource.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceID);
    end;

    //get content height
    resourceid:=Resource.getIdentifier(StringToJString('content'),
          StringToJString('id'),
          StringToJString('android'));
    if resourceID>0 then begin
      view:=SharedActivity.findViewById(resourceID);
    end;
    contentHeight:=view.getHeight;

    //count statusbar height value on form
    FormStatusBarHeight:=round(statusbarheight*self.Height/contentHeight);
    //set padding    
    self.padding.top:=FormStatusBarHeight;
  end;
end;
```

`Self.top` property can indicate that the app is overlapped or not.
If app is overlapped with status bar, `self.top` has value of zero.